# Get specific data from array of objects in PHP

Tags: php, object

I want to get only specific data from an array inside an object.

When I run this code:

```php
$response = $client->__call('get', $request);
$vars = get_object_vars($response); 
print_r($vars);
```

It gives me whole array.

```
Array
(
  [clients] => Array
    (
      [0] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 2
          [guests] => Array
            (
              [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                  [id] => 2
                  [firstName] => Greg
                  [lastName] => Gregson
                )
            )
          [invoiceData] => stdClass Object
            (
              [taxNumber] => 12345678
            )
        )
      [1] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 3
          [guests] => Array
            (
              [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                  [id] => 3
                  [firstName] => Paul
                  [lastName] => Paulson
                )
            )
          [invoiceData] => stdClass Object
            (
              [taxNumber] => 34567891
            )
        )
      [2] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 4
          [guests] => Array
            (
              [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                  [id] => 4
                  [firstName] => John
                  [lastName] => Johnson
                )
            )
          [invoiceData] => stdClass Object
            (
              [taxNumber] => 23456789
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I'd like to see only `[id][firstName][taxNumber]` as one array like below:

```
2, Greg, 12345678
3, Paul, 34567891
4, John, 23456789
```

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**array_walk()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to grab only expected items. An example:

```
array_walk($vars['clients'], function (&$item) {
    $item = ["{$item->id}, {$item->guests[0]->firstName}, {$item->invoiceData->taxNumber}"];
});
```